# facebook.request() with specific fields

Tags: facebook, lua, coronasdk

I am using Corona SDK and I implement facebook integration. I want only 3 specific fields, username, userid and picture. This works `facebook.request('me')`. According to facebook api to get specific fields I have to do `me?fields=id,name,picture`. This returns:

```
{
  "id": "1139209399", 
  "name": "Avraa Makis", 
  "picture": {
    "data": {
      "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/211241_1131205352_495011489_q.jpg", 
      "is_silhouette": false
    }
  }
}
```

So I tried `facebook.request('me?fields=id,name,picture')` but it didn't work. Any idea how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Corona documentation](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/facebook/request.html)

`facebook.request("me", "GET", { fields="id,name,picture" })`

should do the trick.